# How to get fullscreen monitor size even when DisplayDevice is not FullScreen in Java?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fullscreen, screen-size

I'm looking for a Java method that will me screen dimensions in full-screen.
When using,

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
double width = screenSize.getWidth();
double height = screenSize.getHeight();
```

or

```
double width = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().
    getMaximumWindowBounds().getWidth();
```

The width and height values will change whenever the screen changes resolution. I do not understand this measurement, since the width and height values are of the primitive type double (this means that they reside in the stack).

After an exhaustive search I had to resort to this forum because I did not find any methods like `availSize`

Comment: The tags initially included [tag: javafx-8] so I added Java-FX, but the code looks like it comes direct from the AWT package. Which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following method to get all content in full screen and also can call the static method to change scenes just passing the FXML name (another.fxml). Hope you are looking for this:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Main extends Application {


    private static Stage mainStage;

    public static Stage getStage() {
        return mainStage;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        mainStage = stage;


        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));

        Region contentRootRegion = (Region) loader.load();


        Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        double origW = d.width;
        double origH = d.height;

        // Set a default "standard" or "100%" resolution
        // origW = 1360;
        // origH = 700;

        // If the Region containing the GUI does not already have a preferred width and height, set it.
        // But, if it does, we can use that setting as the "standard" resolution.
        if (contentRootRegion.getPrefWidth() == Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE)
            contentRootRegion.setPrefWidth(origW);
        else
            origW = contentRootRegion.getPrefWidth();

        if (contentRootRegion.getPrefHeight() == Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE)
            contentRootRegion.setPrefHeight(origH);
        else
            origH = contentRootRegion.getPrefHeight();

        //Wrap the resizable content in a non-resizable container (Group)
        Group group = new Group(contentRootRegion);
        //Place the Group in a StackPane, which will keep it centered
        StackPane rootPane = new StackPane();
        rootPane.getChildren().add(group);


        //Create the scene iniitally at the "100%" size
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootPane, origW, origH);
        //Bind the scene's width and height to the scaling parameters on the group
        group.scaleXProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty().divide(origW));
        group.scaleYProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty().divide(origH));
        //Set the scene to the window (stage) and show it

        stage.setTitle("My App Name");

        Screen screen = Screen.getPrimary();
        Rectangle2D bounds = screen.getVisualBounds();

        stage.setX(bounds.getMinX());
        stage.setY(bounds.getMinY());
        stage.setWidth(bounds.getWidth());
        stage.setHeight(bounds.getHeight());
        stage.setMaximized(true);

        //stage.setFullScreen(true);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }


    public static void ChangeScene(String FXML) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource(FXML));
            Region contentRootRegion = (Region) loader.load();


            Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            double origW = d.width;
            double origH = d.height;

            if (contentRootRegion.getPrefWidth() == Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE)
                contentRootRegion.setPrefWidth(origW);
            else
                origW = contentRootRegion.getPrefWidth();

            if (contentRootRegion.getPrefHeight() == Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE)
                contentRootRegion.setPrefHeight(origH);
            else
                origH = contentRootRegion.getPrefHeight();

            //Wrap the resizable content in a non-resizable container (Group)
            Group group = new Group(contentRootRegion);
            //Place the Group in a StackPane, which will keep it centered
            StackPane rootPane = new StackPane();
            rootPane.getChildren().add(group);


            //Create the scene initially at the "100%" size
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootPane, origW, origH);
            //Bind the scene's width and height to the scaling parameters on the group
            group.scaleXProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty().divide(origW));
            group.scaleYProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty().divide(origH));
            //Set the scene to the window (stage) and show it

            Screen screen = Screen.getPrimary();
            Rectangle2D bounds = screen.getVisualBounds();

            Main.getStage().setX(bounds.getMinX());
            Main.getStage().setY(bounds.getMinY());
            Main.getStage().setWidth(bounds.getWidth());
            Main.getStage().setHeight(bounds.getHeight());
            //Main.getStage().setMaximized(true);

            Main.getStage().setScene(scene);
            Main.getStage().show();


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```